# Semi-transparent PictureBox (C# Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency, picturebox

Is there a way, in C#, to make a Picturebox semi-transparent so that you can actually see through the PictureBox and see what's behind it?

Comment: What do you want to see? The desktop or another part of the form?

Comment: Just another part of the form. And hopefully, also anything else that may be underneath the picturebox.